# VS Code is not showing marks for error lines in Haskell

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I am using this Haskell Extension in VS Code [Haskell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haskell.haskell) and my installed ghc version is 9.2.1. Now whenever i am writing haskell code in vs code it is not showing any errors. For example in the picture i should have gotten an error mark in the
`shrink :: [a] -> [a]` for not writing `shrink :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` and again in the place  `shrink (x:xs) = x : shrink (dropWhile (== x)`  for not completing the bracket.[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: `9.2.1` is not `hls` powered as far as I know. Downgrade to `9.0.1`.

Comment: how to do that. whenever i am running `choco install haskell-dev` command it is installing 9.2.1

Comment: I'm not sure about `choco`. I use `ghcup` and it has never failed me. It allows me to to install and use the version of `ghci`, `cabal`, `stack` and... I want.

Comment: How do you uninstall ghc